# thinking sphinx multiple classes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, model, thinking-sphinx

I have two models Post and comment and i want to search both using thinking sphinx, I is working fine with single model but give me error "undefined method `sphinx_index_options' for Object:Class" while search both models.

ERROR I faced
     error "undefined method `sphinx_index_options' for Object:Class"

In Post model is

```
define_index do
indexes [topic, body], as: :post
has cached_tag_list, :as => :tag_ids
indexes comments.body, :as => :comment
has created_at 
where "is_private='f'"
end
has_many :comments, :as=>:commentable, :order => "created_at asc", :dependent =>:destroy
```

and comments model

```
define_index do
indexes [body, other], as: :comment
has created_at
end
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
```

and in my controller query is

```
if params[:query]
@query = params[:query]
page = params[:page] || 1
@search = ThinkingSphinx.search @query, :classes=>[Post, Comment],    :order=>:created_at, :sort_mode=>:desc, :field_weights=>{:topic=>2.0}, :per_page=>15, :page=>page
```

@total_entries = @search.total_entries
   else
   render :action => :search_form,
   end

Comment: error is undefined method `sphinx_index_options' for Object:Class

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of that error?

Comment: Processing by Portal::PostsController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"knee"}
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Sphinx Query (21.5ms)  knee
  Sphinx  Found 987 results
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `sphinx_index_options' for Object:Class):
  app/controllers/portal/posts_controller.rb:123:in `search'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of Single Table Inheritance. Update your thinking sphinx gem ~> 2.0.12.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your relationships before your index.